# Playing text to speech inside read function in asterisk

Tags: asterisk, text-to-speech, voip, ivr, dtmf

So my basic aim is to take dtmf while the google text to speech agi is playing.In case of sound file i can simply use read function ,so the user is allowed to press dtmf while sound is been playing and the input is stored in a variable.For ex

```
[mycon]
exten => _X.,1,Read(KEY,soundfile,,)
```

But how can i take dtmf input while playing text to speech agi

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have record TTS to wav file(8khz 16 bit mono pcm uncompressed format REQUIRED) and use something like this

```
[mycon]
exten => _X.,1,Read(KEY,soundfile&/tmp/tts/tts-file&other-sound,,)
```

You also can generate that file, save in variable and use that variable instead of file name.

Also you can use app_swift application which do that for you(for cepstral and some other TTS,not google). http://www.cepstral.com/en/telephony/asterisk

Third possible solution - write c/c++ app like app_swift for google or hire someone to write that.